# Use induction to demonstrate properties of the sequence $a_1 = 4$, $a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n+6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I just can't understand how to approach this question, which is probably very easy. Tried to look online for solutions but didn't come across something helpful. Here's the question:

There is a series where:
$a_1 = 4$,
$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_{n}+6}$.

Prove by induction:

1. For every natural $n$ number: $a_{n}>3$
2. Prove that $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$ for every natural n

I understand the idea of induction, as finding something valid for the first member of the group, assuming it's true for the $n$ object and showing it's indeed correct for the $(n+1)$-st object. I just can't understand how to pull this off on this question.

Comment: More than "understanding the idea" you must get used to it. Try to follow some examples of proofs by induction and you'll see that these ones are very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, use $x>3\implies\sqrt{x+6}>\sqrt{3+6}=3$ in the inductive step. For the second, you don't need an extra proof by induction: use the result of the first part together with$$x>3\implies x^2-x-6=(x-3)(x+2)>0\implies x+6<x^2\implies\sqrt{x+6}<x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Base cases are trivial then for the induction step for point $1$ assume that $a_n >3$ then

$$a_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_{n}+6} >\sqrt{3+6}=3$$

and for point $2$ assume $a_{n} \geq a_{n+1}$ then

$$a_{n+2} = \sqrt{a_{n+1}+6}\le \sqrt{a_{n}+6}=a_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hints for the inductive steps:

1. If $a_n>3$ then $a_n+6>9$, so $a_{n+1}^2>9$, so $a_{n+1}>3.$
2. If $a_n>3$ then $(a_n-3)(a_n+2)>0$, so $a_n^2-a_n-6>0$, so $a_n>\sqrt{a_n+6}=a_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Supoose $a_n\geq a_{n-1}$. Then, for $a_{n+1}\geq a_{n}$, we have $\sqrt{a_n+6}\geq\sqrt{a_{n-1}+6}$ which completes the proof, because we assumed $a_n\geq a_{n-1}$.

Suppose $a_n\geq 3$ Then $a_{n+1}\geq3$ is equivalent to $\sqrt{a_n+6}\geq3$ and by squaring the proof is done.